# Can I have a scalar function and a stored procedure with the same name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use a stored procedure to generate an internal number (accessible via the `OUTPUT` keyword).

As you cannot use the stored procedure inside a statement, I thought it would be a good idea to just create a function which just calls the stored procedure with its parameters and returns the `OUTPUT` value. So I could directly use it for statements.

Is it possible to name a stored procedure and a scalar function the same in one database, and is this a good idea?

Comment: *"create a function which just calls the stored procedure"* you can't do this; you can't `EXEC` in a `FUNCTION` (apart from a very select few system procedures).

Comment: Why have the procedure at all? Sounds like you could do everything you want to do with just a function. But please make it an in-line table-valued function and not a scalar.

Comment: The procedure does some logic to generate a internal number which increments due to some background logic. I tried it and it basically works. But as @Larnu mentioned I cannot call it directly. Thats something I didnt know...

Comment: @AaronBertrand why a table-valued function? I just need the single value from the `OUTPUT`, not more.

Comment: Because, at least on older versions, scalar functions aren't inlinable, @Me3nTaL , and even on 2019+ there are *a lot* of gotchas.

Comment: Also it makes it more flexible. With scalar functions people tend to put them in a `SELECT` list, e.g. `SELECT ID, dbo.SomeFunc(col) FROM ...` and this can be horrible performance-wise. Whether you need a single independent value or `SELECT ID, f.col FROM ... CROSS APPLY dbo.SomeFunc(col)`, an inline table-valued function can do both, efficiently.

Comment: The answer is "no" anyway. Within a schema object names must be unique irrespective of type ("object" being something with its own entry in `sys.objects`)

Comment: Okay thanks for the responses. My primary question is answered.

Comment: @MartinSmith altough theese objects are differentiated by their type which is different for a stored procedure and a function. If it is being a good practise is another thing...

Comment: "irrespective of type" means that doesn't make any difference. You can't have a stored proc and a function share a name any more than you can have two functions share a name

Comment: The name would be the same but the corresponding `type` of the `sys.objects` entry could identify the sp and the function, since its different as well as the `type_desc`

Comment: Yeah and If my Grandmother had wheels she would have been a bike. This is not how the product is designed

Comment: Yes, as I said, if this is a good practice is another question, but thank you for your evaluation.

Comment: if this is a good practice is an irrelevant question because it isn't possible anyway

Comment: On SQL Sever 2012 it is technically possible as I tried it out just now.

Comment: That gives error "There is already an object named 'Foo' in the database." too. Either you gave them different names or created them in different schemas.

Comment: You are right, excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply answer the question (thanks to Martin):
No, I can't.

The error message raised is Error 2714 ("There is already an object named 'Foo' in the database.").

Comment: In `sys.sysschobjs` (the underlying system table behind `sys.objects`) the combination of `name,nsid,nsclass` is constrained to be unique. This does not include the `type` column. `name` is just name. `nsid` is schema id. `nsclass` is a categorisation different than type (e.g. used to differentiate DDL triggers)

Answer (score 0):

A complete name of any relational object in a database is a name in two parts :

1. the schema name, that is in fact a container inside the database
2. the object_name, that is an unique name relative to the schema

As a demo you can do :

```
CREATE SCHEMA S_SQL;
GO

CREATE USER U_SQL WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = S_SQL;
GO

GRANT CONTROL TO U_SQL;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'U_SQL';
GO

CREATE FUNCTION F_FOO()
RETURNS CHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN 
   RETURN 'foo';
END;
GO

REVERT;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE F_FOO
AS
RETURN 'oof';
GO

SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;
```

You will have the same object name, but in two differerent schemas...